# Inverse relation in realm

Tags: realm

Let's assume two tables `Box`and `Item`. Box may have many items, one item have only one box. I would like to fetch all items which have box is in given array. How could I do that? In CD I would do it by predicate and property in `Item` class which stands for connection to Box.

I am using version 0.81

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UPDATE (10-27-2014)

Bidirectional relationships are now supported. See Realm's docs: http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/latest#inverse-relationships

ORIGINAL ANSWER

Bidirectional relationships must be explicitly linked at this time. Here's an example:

```
@class Box;

@interface Item : RLMObject
@property Box *box;
@end

RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(Item);

@interface Box : RLMObject
@property RLMArray<Item> *items;
@end

...

Item *item = [[Item alloc] init];
Box *box = [[Box alloc] initWithObject:@[@[item]]];
item.box = box;
```

We have plans to simplify this pattern in the future.

This answer was taken from [GitHub](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/677#issuecomment-50182237)

Comment: Thanks, jpsim.  If I'm not mistaken we'll need a forward declaration above that code: `@class Box;`

Comment: All Android updates will be posted to https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/607